# Ping returns "ip no resources"

Tags: windows-7, ping, windows-command-prompt

One of my clients networks keeps losing connectivity, either the network or the PC they are trying to connect to.

I am running a ping from the PC to the router which runs fine most of the time and occasionally returns:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.254 bytes=32 ip no resources
```

What does the **ip no resources** bit mean? Any clues as to what it means for the connectivity issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ping is succeeding, but you're receiving ICMP code 11006 back "no resources". I am no expert in this matter, but it may mean the network stack on the destination is out of ports to be able to communicate with the client, or perhaps that it only allocates so many ports per client.

I would check for: misbehaving firewall configurations, misbehaving anti-virus clients, and do no skip checking layers 1-4, physical cable, adapter, drivers and link negotiation, TCP/IP configuration, etc.

Comment: That's about what I though... It's definitely an error. But who knows where...

Comment: Some research, with emphasis on some, indicates the presence of virus/spyware might be the cause.

Comment: Unfortunately their network is not controlled by us. But because the computer we put in is new it becomes our fault so I just need to prove that the issue is not the new PC so I have something to go to their IT guys with.

Comment: If the address `192.168.1.254` belongs to the aforementioned router, the issue is quite clear - the *router* is answering with `ip no resources` - your host has nothing to do with it. You could run another ping to a host behind the router to see if the `ip no resources` response would come up occasionally as well.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Their host could be responsible if it has a bad NIC, Driver, Speed/duplex setting, etc. 

Also, themodem , I would suggest doing a netstat -a on your host to see if there's a lot of outbound connections.